# How to connect to password protected SSID and open SSID programmatically without duplicationg a wi-fi network

Tags: android, android-wifi

When i connect to particular SSID it creates a duplicate network everytime i connect to SSId to programmatically.

Here's my code which i use to connect to SSID

```
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfiguration.SSID="\"xsinfosol\"";
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey="\""+ networkPASS +"\"";
        //wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "connect to::"+networkSSID, 0).show();

        int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
        //wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Please help